# SQL prepare failed: (1136) Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm getting a 1136 error on my SQL query.
You can see my query below. The error pops up because of the first if statement. The first column in my table is the ID field, but this is set to auto_increment. So this shouldn't be the cause of the problem, right?
Can somebody tell me where I'm messing up?

```
function CreateNewItem($titelNL, $titelEN, $technieken, $jaar, $yt, $beschrijvingNL, $description, $user)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO portfolioItem (titel_nl, beschrijving_nl, leerjaar, datum, auteur_id, technieken, titel_en, beschrijving_en, youtubeLink)
                    VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR), ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $databaseConn = $this->connect();

        if (!($stmt = $databaseConn->prepare($sql))) {
            echo "Prepare failed: (" . $databaseConn->errno . ") " . $databaseConn->error;
            return;
        }
        if (!$stmt->bind_param("ssiissss", $titelNL, $beschrijvingNL, $jaar, $user->id, $technieken, $titelEN, $description, $yt)) {
            echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            return;
        }   
        if (!$stmt->execute()) {
            echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
            return;
        }
        $id = $stmt->insert_ID;
        $stmt->close();
        $this->closeConnection();
        return $id;
    }
```

Comment: There are 9 fields but only 8 values in your query.

Comment: are talking about the "datum," field? because I fill that in by using the DATE_ADD methode. Or is it better to create a variable for it and the pass that on as a paramater in the bind_param method?

Comment: Do not include the `auto_increment` column in your insert statement.

Comment: @YusufHassan at this moment it is not included. Which is what baffles me about this issue. The error is stating that I'm not passing a value for the first column, but I'm not even inserting anything into the first column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INSERT statement references *nine* columns, but there are only *eight* values.

```
  INSERT INTO portfolioItem
  ( titel_nl                           -- c1
  , beschrijving_nl                    -- c2
  , leerjaar                           -- c3
  , datum                              -- c4
  , auteur_id                          -- c5
  , technieken                         -- c6
  , titel_en                           -- c7
  , beschrijving_en                    -- c8
  , youtubeLink                        -- c9
  ) VALUES 
  ( ?                                  -- v1
  , ?                                  -- v2
  , ?                                  -- v3  
  , DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)   -- v4
  , ?                                  -- v5
  , ?                                  -- v6
  , ?                                  -- v7
  , ?                                  -- v8
  )
```

This is why MySQL is throwing a syntax error.

Looking at the bind values being supplied, it looks like you are missing one "comma question mark" in the values.

```
  , $titelNL                      // bind v1
  , $beschrijvingNL               // bind v2 
  , $jaar                         // bind v3
                                  //      v4 is a literal 
  , $user->id                     // bind v5
  , $technieken                   // bind v6
  , $titelEN                      // bind v7
  , $description                  // bind v8
  , $yt                           // bind v9
```

Comment: I feel so stupid now, I have counted the fields and columns a dozen times and still messed up. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @JoshuaVolkers: dollars to donuts i bet you were counting *commas*, and counting the comma inside the DATE_ADD function. My personal preference is to specify `NOW() + INTERVAL 2 HOUR` in place of the `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 HOUR)`.  And also list each column and each value on separate lines. Yeah, it gets long. But its much easier to read than scrolling over to the right to read a long line of SQL

Comment: I might just use the same method of typing it out on seperate lines. Makes for a much easier reading experience, especially when you've been at it for a couple of hours.